# Javascript Promises and console log?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, puppeteer

I need help with Javascript Promises.

The `buttons` - is a NodeList. I get it from `puppeteer` ([API](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageselector-1)).
I need a list of the buttons with a specific text.
I transform `buttons` to array of real buttons ([page.evaluate API link](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args)):

- I map through the array,
- Convert it to a button,
- Check the text and `return null` if the text isn't what I need
- I `console.log` the button text - and it shows me the text I need - so it's all good.
- Then I increment `counter`
- And return the converted button.

After that I filter the array - checking for not null elements.
I expect that `goodButtons` would contain only the buttons I need - with the correct text.

But the output is

```
buttons 328
button: Confirm
button: Confirm
... 100 lines of "good button text" in total
button: Confirm
counter 0
good buttons 328
```

So the counter does not increment once (or there's a trick with `async`/`await` stuff and `console.log` that I'm missing?)
BUT it seems that `goodButtons` array contains ALL THE BUTTONS somehow, although button text that I logged in console seems correct.

The code

```js
const buttons = await page.$$('button[type="button"]')
console.log('buttons', await buttons.length)

let counter = 0;
let goodButtons = await buttons.map(async button => {
    const btnText = await page.evaluate(btn => btn.innerText, button);

    if (!['Confirm'].includes(btnText)) return null

    counter++
    console.log('button: ', btnText)

    return await button
}).filter(button => button !== null)

console.log('counter', counter)
console.log('good buttons', await goodButtons.length)
```

**UPD** (after Felix Kling comment)

```js
let counter = 0;
let goodButtons = buttons.map(async button => {
        const btnText = await page.evaluate(btn => btn.innerText, button);

        if (!['Confirm', 'Подтвердить'].includes(btnText)) return null

        counter++

        return await button
})
goodButtons = await Promise.all(goodButtons)
goodButtons = goodButtons.filter(button => button !== null)
```

Output

```
buttons 328
counter 149
good buttons 328
```

Comment: `Array#map` does not return a promise. You need to use `Promise.all`. `button` in the `.filter` call actually refers to a promise, which is always `!== null`.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please?  @FelixKling

I changed it to `goodButtons = await Promise.all(goodButtons)`  
And now the `counter` works - it shows good buttons count.  
But the `goodButtons` array still contains all 328 elements.  

And thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: I updated the question with the new code and output

Comment: You dont filter at the updated code after Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` functions return a promise.

Hence `buttons.map( async function)` returns an array of promises, some of which have been fulfilled with `null` (by returning `null` from the map function), while all the others have been fulfilled by returning a `button` element handle supplied to the map function.

You can use `Promise.all` to convert the array of promises into an array from which you can filter out the `null` values:

```
let counter = 0;

let goodButtons =  (await Promise.all(
    buttons.map(async button => {
        const btnText = await page.evaluate(btn => btn.innerText, button);

        if (!['Confirm', 'Подтвердить'].includes(btnText)) return null

        counter++
        return button
   }))
   .filter(button => button !== null)
```

Note that the `length` property of an array is a number so there is no need to `await` it.

Similarly `button` in a puppeteer elementHandle object, not a promise if I have read the documentation correctly, so it shouldn't require `await` before it either.

(Edit: with thanks to Andrew P. - the filter function must be applied to the array
returned by `await Promise.all(....` )

Comment: apparently we should wrap it like that 
`(await Promise.all(...)).filter(...)`

Comment: Agreed, I reworded your suggested edit but the result should be equivalent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code after @Felix Kling's comment and @Ufuk's tip.

Thank you guys!

```js
let counter = 0;
let goodButtons = buttons.map(async button => {
        const btnText = await page.evaluate(btn => btn.innerText, button);

        if (!['Confirm', 'Подтвердить'].includes(btnText)) return null

        counter++

        return await button
})
goodButtons = await Promise.all(goodButtons)
goodButtons = goodButtons.filter(button => button !== null)
```

Output

```
buttons 328
counter 149
good buttons 149
```